# why after including foreach loop i''m getting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

After Including the following selected line in Imag i'm getting error else it works fine.
[image]

Comment: You can't add code in the middle of the initialization of a class.

Comment: @Gusman How can i implemet that?

Comment: Compose the list outside the initialization code. You can skip that step if you create the XAxisModels in the Select method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** add code in the middle of the initialization of a class.

You can do this

```cs
var BarCharModel = new ChartModel<int>
{
    Title = "Month",
    XaxisCategories = new List<XAxisModel>() { }
};
foreach(var item in xaxis)
{
    //replace item with your XaxisCategories model
    BarCharModel.XaxisCategories.Add(item);
}
//or do this instead of foreach
//replace "a" with your XaxisCategories model
xaxis.ForEach(a=> { BarCharModel.XaxisCategories.Add(a); } );
```

Answer (score -1):

Revert the logic. Inside the foreach loop, place the new list initilization

Answer (score -1):

I found three problems in your program
First : you forgot to add constructor parenthesis after `new ChartModel<int>` .
Second : you cannot initialize a class variable inside initialization of a class, 
I mean the place of `XaxisCategories = new List<XAxisModel>()` is the constructor of the class.
Third : you cannot have foreach loop in class initialization (you can't even call a function to set a variable there)
you should pass variable `XaxisCategories` data via constructor